# Stop setText() from showing Android soft keyboard on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

Given `EditText et;`

When I programatically call `et.setText("Hello World")` a soft keyboard appears on the screen.

I want to prevent this soft keyboard from showing up. I don't mind if `et` remains focused or not.

I have tried `et.clearFocus();`

I still want to be able to focus on `et` and show the keyboard when tapping on it. Just not from `et.setText()`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code programmatically. But if you just want to display text use `TextView`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: But I want the keyboard to still show when I tap on the `EditText`

Comment: Just remove the word ALWAYS from the plag (editted code) . The keyboard will be called if not you can enable it manually in onClickListener of your edittext

Comment: Should this be called directly after `setText()`, because this won't work. Should there be a listener to detect when keyboard shows?

Comment: this should be called before setting text

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `manifest.xml` to your `<activity/>` tag:-

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

like:-

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

> `setText()` wont show up the keyboard

Comment: But I want the keyboard to still show when I tap on the `EditText`

Comment: yes it will show up when you tap the keyboard... @GregPeckory

Comment: update if the answer works.. !! @GregPeckory

Comment: Keyboard never show now

Comment: it should show when you tap the editText.. i have used this in all of my apps !! @GregPeckory

Comment: this is the correct answer ! android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" also works fine.

Comment: You can also use `et.getText().clear()` and then `et.getText().append(...)`. This won't open soft keyboard like just callling `et.setText(...)` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent keyboard to display do like this

```
        et.setText("Hello World")
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
```